# Developing Event Receivers in Sharepoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm new to Sharepoint 2016.  I've been using Sharepoint Foundation 2010 to develop an event receiver for Sharepoint 2010.  Now I'm looking to do the same thing for Sharepoint 2016.  I cannot find a Sharepoint Foundation 2016 kit.  Where can I get the tools and libraries I need to develop the event receivers for 2016?

Answer (score 1):

Just like @andersbs is stating - You need to install the SDK.

For this you must use Visual Studio 2015 or above. If you are using Visual Studio 2017 I'd recommend to use the Visual Studio Installer to install this SDK.

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Installer adding SharePoint SDK]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the SP 2016 SDK from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51679

Then you can create a new project in Visual Studio.

Read more about the methods for development for SharePoint 2016 here:

https://dev.office.com/blogs/using-correct-csom-version-for-sharepoint-customizations